# Dataset data is different that stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure.

```
SELECT ADDRESS.ADDRESSID, NAME, DOORNO, STREET, STATE, COUNT(SUB.ADDRESSID) AS FREQUENCY
FROM ADDRESS 
JOIN
(
(SELECT ADDRESSID FROM ADDRESS WHERE KEYWORD LIKE '%' + @name + '%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT ADDRESSID FROM ADDRESS WHERE KEYWORD LIKE '%' + @doorno + '%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT ADDRESSID FROM ADDRESS WHERE KEYWORD LIKE '%' + @street + '%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT ADDRESSID FROM ADDRESS WHERE KEYWORD LIKE '%' + @state + '%')
) 
SUB
ON SUB.ADDRESSID=ADDRESS.ADDRESSID
GROUP BY ADDRESS.ADDRESSID, NAME, DOORNO, STREET, STATE
ORDER BY FREQUENCY DESC
```

When I am executing this manually, I am getting correct results.
Lets say these are the results

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║     DOORNO     ║       STREET        ║ STATE ║ FREQUENCY ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║  4 ║ John ║ 29             ║ Police Station      ║ DC    ║         3 ║
║  1 ║ John ║ Door 13-9-16/A ║ patimeeda           ║ NJ    ║         2 ║
║  3 ║ Paul ║ Plot 304       ║ Near Police Station ║ NJ    ║         1 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

But when I am calling this SP from C# code using Sqldataadapter and dataset I am always getting the FREQUENCY AS 1
Like below.

```
╔════╦══════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║     DOORNO     ║       STREET        ║ STATE ║ FREQUENCY ║
╠════╬══════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ John ║ Door 13-9-16/A ║ patimeeda           ║ NJ    ║         1 ║
║  3 ║ Paul ║ Plot 304       ║ Near Police Station ║ NJ    ║         1 ║
║  4 ║ John ║ 29             ║ Police Station      ║ DC    ║         1 ║
╚════╩══════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Sorting is very important for me. Any idea why I am losing this?

C#.NET code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Add_GetAddressSearchResults", con);
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=addressModel.Name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@doorno", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=addressModel.DoorNo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=addressModel.Street;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value=addressModel.State;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds= new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ds.WriteXml("c:/ram.xls"); // to check the data
```

Comment: can you add code where you call procedure?

Comment: are you sure the sqldataadapter is talking to the same server, the same named instance, the same database, calling the same sp, and in particular the same **version** of the sp? A common error is to run `rams.my_proc` in the SQL tools (SSMS), but run `dbo.myproc` via the sql-data-adapter or similar.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have only one server and db and I am sure that I am executing correct proc. I have the same doubt and i tried changing the name of the column FREQUENCY as FREQUENCI and tested to conform that i am talking to same DB. It is very strange..!

Comment: @GuruStron I added my C#.net code in the main question..

Comment: @Rams agreed; very strange. If you call `ExecuteReader` and look throw the rows by hand - are the results correct *there*? Just trying to narrow down where the problem is starting...

Comment: @MarcGravell will give a try and let you know. I need some time, have to go to office..

Comment: If `Frequency` in your table adapter an int?

Comment: @MilenPavlov  I am not defining my table adapter. I am just using dataAdapter.Fill() to populate it.

Comment: #winces# I dislike that you're getting the same results multiple times, then grouping them together to get the count of matches.  Feels like you're making the db do more work than it should be.  That said, I don't have a better way to do it without resorting to putting the conditions in two places; does anyone with more SQL Server experience know if there's a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

If you've eliminated other obvious reasons (different database, different query, ...), I would strongly suspect you have NULL values in the ADDRESSID column, and that [ANSI_NULLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) is configured differently.

I believe the default for a C# connection is different from the defaults in SQL Server Management Studio.

To test this, experiment with setting ANSI_NULLS on and off when executing the query manually, and/or try modifying the query to explicitly handle NULLs the way you want to, e.g. something like:

```
ON ISNULL(SUB.ADDRESSID,0)=ISNULL(ADDRESS.ADDRESSID,0)
```

You could also try setting this (and other similar settings like ANSI_PADDING) explicitly in the Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but `SUB` you are extracting from subquery is again containing records for `ADDRESS` and inner join on `ADDRESSID` is likely to give frequency as 1 unless `SUB` contains more than what you have in `ADDRESS`, your correct result would be because passed parameter is giving you superset of `ADDRESS` in `SUB`